# GWT Remote logging with log4j

Tags: java, spring, gwt, logging

I want to log GWT client side logs to a log file present in server(My application is GWT-Springs based).

I have done following changes:

1)In gwt.xml file inlcuded below lines

```
a)<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/> 
b)<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
```

2)In GWT java file I have below code

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myClassName");
  logger.info("log the message");
```

3)In web.xml I have defined servlet as follows

```
<servlet>    
<servlet-name>remoteLoggingServlet</servlet-name>    
<servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>    
  <servlet-name>remoteLoggingServlet</servlet-name>    
  <url-pattern>/module_name/remote_logging</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

4)In Springs I have log4j Configuration which is logging all logs in service/dao layer to a log file.

However I am unable to print GWT logs to the log file present in server

1)Can someone help on this issue?

2)Also I am unable to understand the flow of GWT logs to a log file in server?

3)What is the Significance of `<url-pattern>/module_name/remote_logging</url-pattern>`

4)What should be present after module_name/ in URL pattern

5)Is /remote_logging mapped anywhere else?